# Android Studio throws "unresolved reference" error, but no error in code

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

So, the question in the title.

I updated the project from GitHub, started on AVD, it works - no errors were found.
But after I added/modified some code parts, again without errors, whenever I try to run app, the compiler throws :

```
e:%path/%class.kt :{n,y}     
Unresolved references: %methodname
```

I clicked on the error link and it's an open screen with added/modified code, but still, IDE doesn't show any error in the code.

I tried to run similar code on another machine - it worked just fine, with no error.
Restart/Invalidate cache not working.

Specs
Android Studio version - Arctic Fox RC 1 (2020.3.1.21)
Kotlin version - 1.5.21
Gradle version - 7.2

If this question is a duplicate, please provide a link for similar questions with answers.
Thank you.